# Anything better than resorting to libc for arbitrary protocols over raw sockets?

Tags: rust, network-programming

The `nix` crate is a nice wrapper around libc for working with raw sockets, but it turns out that it only supports the TCP and UDP protocols over those [raw sockets](https://doc.servo.org/src/nix/sys/socket/mod.rs.html#80-93). I want to use, say, ICMP over raw sockets--as in, I want to use `sendto` with an ICMP packet and have it end up wrapped in an IP header + Ethernet header before heading out onto the network, just as it would with the standard libc functions. Are there any wrappers/crates out there that support this without me resorting to doing ugly FFI stuff myself? It would be great if there were a way to use `getprotobyname` or something similar with nix.

Comment: Did you take a look at the [`pnet` crate](https://docs.rs/pnet)?

Answer (score 1):

The Rust standard library currently has no raw socket capabilities. [The lowest level networking library](https://docs.rs/pcap/0.7.0/pcap/) in existence is a direct FFI to `libpcap`. If you want to use any protocol besides TCP or UDP via the standard library, you'll have to implement it yourself or see if [pnet](https://docs.rs/pnet/0.25.0/pnet/) has already done it.

Using [pcap](https://docs.rs/pcap/0.7.0/pcap/):

```
let mut handle = Device::lookup().unwrap().open().unwrap();

let data = &[0, 1, 2, 3, 5];

handle.sendpacket(data);
```